# NDIS.SYS driver very high latency in Windows 10

Tags: networking, drivers, windows-10, dpc

I have upgraded my computer from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. The installation went well, no problem occurred.

My motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4315#ov). After the install, I updated the Realtek drivers to their latest Windows 10 version.

After I started to use the new Windows 10, I experienced sudden freezes, the audio or video playback is stopped for a very short time.

I checked the driver latencies with LatencyMonitor and DPC Latency Checker.

They both showed very high values (*100-200 000, even 600 0000 microseconds*), and it seems that ***NDIS.SYS*** causes the problem.

As this file is network related, I tested it with another LAN card (an ASUS PCI LAN card), it has a very different driver.

*Surprisingly*, this LAN card also shows very high values (not as often as the Realtek).

Realtek:

[image: Realtek latency]

ASUS:

[image: ASUS latency]

What should I do now?

**UPDATE**

I installed Windows 10 again.

I use a torrent client (uTorrent) that is set to autostart.
If I quit the client, I get *normal* values.

[image]

What parameter should I check in my torrent client to avoid the problem?

Comment: update the lan drivers. if you still have DPC issues, install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/B/90B9A880-C3F8-43FB-B8F9-E4D4BFB5C85F/standalonesdk/sdksetup.exe), capture a xperf trace (http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD) and share (OneDrive) the compressed ETL file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have created the capture, you can check here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8aAkabXOq4vcmhoUElFNUI4WFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I dumped a statistic about DPCs (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe" -I highCPUUsage.etl -a dpcisr > dpc.txt`) and this shows 2 DPCs which are critical (over 1024µs):

```
Total = 19697 for module ndis.sys
Elapsed Time, >      512 usecs AND <=     1024 usecs,      1, or   0.01%
Total,                                                 19697

Total = 7174 for module tcpip.sys
Elapsed Time, >      512 usecs AND <=     1024 usecs,      1, or   0.01%
```

I checked the NDIS.sys call stacks and saw that 2 rd party files are involved. `ipgdnd60.sys` is the ASUS Gigabit network driver and `vfilter.sys` (VPN driver). Update both and look what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Normally I don't use the VPN connection, so `vfilter.sys` shouldn't be used (if I'm correct). I'm afraid, there are no newer driver versions, but I will look for them :(

Comment: I checked the drivers, there is no new version available. The ShrewSoft VPN driver (vfilter.sys) is disabled, yet I still experience DPC issues. What else can I do?

Comment: remove the VPN software completely and capture a new trace (1-2 minutes)

Comment: I removed the VPN software and created a new capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8aAkabXOq4vV3hIcnpXQ1pQNEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this time the ndis.sys shows a large spike **Elapsed Time, >     8192 usecs AND <=    16384 usecs**. Here the ASUS driver and virtualbox driver is shown in the call stack

Comment: What should I do now? Should I go back to the On-board LAN?

Comment: yes, go back to realtek and capture a new trace

Comment: I have removed the ASUS card and now I have the Realtek capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8aAkabXOq4vUzNIOWtQeVlfZk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this time 3 dpcs from ndis.sys and tcpip.sys cause it. your realtek driver is a bit old. Try the new 10.006.1001.2015: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: Still experiencing some issues. Here is the capture after updating the driver: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8aAkabXOq4vX3psZm5xUXhoQlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: still the same (some small DPCs from ndis.sys/tcpip.sys). In the realtek driver settings (device manager) activate all offloading options.

Comment: They are all set to Enabled. Should I set them to Disabled?

Comment: enabled is good. I currently have no real idea how to fix it.

Comment: Should I buy a new motherboard? I really find it strange that with two different LAN cards I still experience the issue.  And also very strange that with Windows 8.1 (that has a very similar driver model) I did not have the issue.

Comment: maybe Win10 is more sensitive to the DPC issues. I only sometimes use Win10 in a VM and don't use audio in the VM.

Comment: "Fortunately", Windows 10 has a feature to revert back to Windows 8.1. I did that, now I use Windows 8.1 with driver version 8.001.0510.2013, and I don't experience any DPC issues. Too bad, that they changed only 2 thing in Windows 10: the color of the taskbar and the DPC sensitivity. Thanks for your efforts, we can't fight bad programming...

Comment: ok. If you did the free upgrade you can later still try to update to Win10 again and look if it is better.

Answer (score 1):

I have identified the problem with LatencyMon software.

The NIC's RSS queue is distributed across CPU cores, but the core #0 has a lot of interrupts.

The DPC Latency spikes are gone finaly at me:

Try this PowerShell cmdlet:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterRss -Name "*"

Output something like this:

Name                                            : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription                            : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Enabled                                         : True
NumberOfReceiveQueues                           : 4
Profile                                         : NUMAstatic
BaseProcessor: [Group:Number]                   : 0:0
MaxProcessor: [Group:Number]                    : 0:6
MaxProcessors                                   : 4
RssProcessorArray: [Group:Number/NUMA Distance] : 0:0/0  0:2/0  0:4/0  0:6/0
IndirectionTable: [Group:Number]

Then set the NIC's profile to "Closest":
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-NetAdapterRss -Name "Ethernet" -Profile Closest

List again:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterRss -Name "*"

Name                                            : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription                            : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Enabled                                         : True
NumberOfReceiveQueues                           : 4
Profile                                         : Closest
BaseProcessor: [Group:Number]                   : 0:0
MaxProcessor: [Group:Number]                    : 0:6
MaxProcessors                                   : 4
RssProcessorArray: [Group:Number/NUMA Distance] : 0:0/0  0:2/0  0:4/0  0:6/0
IndirectionTable: [Group:Number]

Some resource for this topic:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterrss?view=windowsserver2022-ps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/set-netadapterrss?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Maybe worth trying to assign each RSS queue to other cores than 0 with NUMAstatic but I did not try it because my problem is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This tweak helped a bunch on an Intel system; it doesn't seem to do anything on an AMD PC. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues with the **ndis.sys**. I've tried a lot of solutions and so far none of then really helped me, but recently i managed to fix the problem with the following configurations:

- [Enable NIC interrupt moderation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPv7x.jpg)
- [Set NIC interrupt moderation rate to Extreme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gol7.jpg)
- [Enable Receive Segment Coalescing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3psML.jpg) (Run powershell as administrator the following command `Set-NetOffloadGlobalSetting -ReceiveSegmentCoalescing Enabled`